# Laravel pass parameter to route

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined a route below:

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', array(
    'as' => 'profile-user',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
));
```

And now I am trying to block access to the login and register page when the user is already logged in, so I have the following code:

```
if(!Auth::guest()) {
    return Redirect::route('profile-user');
}
```

but then it puts `/user/{username}` in the URL and gives a `404 NotFoundHttpException` error.

How can I pass something to replace the `{username}` in the `Redirect::route('profile-user');`? Because it works if you type into the URL `/user/username`, so there must be a way to get the code to do that?

Comment: This doesn't really make a lot of sense.  If you are trying to block users that already signed in from going to that route, why are you redirecting to that same route in the filter?

Comment: No, that route is to go to the user page, I am trying to redirect them off of the login / register page

Answer (score 1):

```
return Redirect::route('profile-user',$parameter_to_pass);
```

Which is in this case:

```
return Redirect::route('profile-user', ['username' => Auth::user()->username]);
```

Comment: can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: it's just 2 lines of code with no explanation at all... not sure if that makes it a good answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally. I you need to use an `action` instead of the route. So to I used this code:

```
if(!Auth::guest()) {
    return Redirect::action('ProfileController@user', [Auth::user()->username]);
}
```

Comment: You can use `route`, check the updated answer of 'user3073415', it's right answer.

Comment: No it is not necessary to use controller action we can do with route also